# Regex to match xml tag with multiple attributes

Tags: regex, docx

I'm trying to find a regular expression that can match the tag `<w:proofErr .... />`.

The regex101 link: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tO1fK0/1)

The original string is:

```
<w:pPr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:autoSpaceDE w:val="0"/><w:autoSpaceDN w:val="0"/><w:adjustRightInd w:val="0"/><w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:cs="SerifGothicStd-Bold"/><w:b/><w:bCs/><w:sz w:val="24"/><w:szCs w:val="24"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:proofErr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:type="spellStart"/><w:proofErr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:type="gramStart"/><w:r xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:rsidRPr="008D22B1"><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:cs="SerifGothicStd-Bold"/><w:b/><w:bCs/><w:sz w:val="24"/><w:szCs w:val="24"/></w:rPr><w:t>student</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:type="spellEnd"/><w:proofErr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:type="gramEnd"/><w:r xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:rsidRPr="008D22B1"><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:cs="SerifGothicStd-Bold"/><w:b/><w:bCs/><w:sz w:val="24"/><w:szCs w:val="24"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:proofErr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:type="spellStart"/><w:r xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:rsidRPr="008D22B1"><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:cs="SerifGothicStd-Bold"/><w:b/><w:bCs/><w:sz w:val="24"/><w:szCs w:val="24"/></w:rPr><w:t>learning</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:type="spellEnd"/><w:r xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:rsidRPr="008D22B1"><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:cs="SerifGothicStd-Bold"/><w:b/><w:bCs/><w:sz w:val="24"/><w:szCs w:val="24"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:proofErr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:type="spellStart"/><w:r xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:rsidRPr="008D22B1"><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:cs="SerifGothicStd-Bold"/><w:b/><w:bCs/><w:sz w:val="24"/><w:szCs w:val="24"/></w:rPr><w:t>outcomes</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:type="spellEnd"/><w:r xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:rsidRPr="008D22B1"><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:cs="SerifGothicStd-Bold"/><w:b/><w:bCs/><w:sz w:val="24"/><w:szCs w:val="24"/></w:rPr><w:t>*</w:t></w:r><w:autoSpaceDE xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:val="0"/><w:autoSpaceDN xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" w:val="0"/>
```

And I'm trying with the following regex:

```
/<w:proofErr.+(?:\/>)/g
```

But when I run it there's only one big match with all the text starting in the first `<w:prrofErr` and finishing at the end of the string.

How can I use a regex to match every `<w:proofErr .... />`?

Comment: Why are you trying to extract data from XML using regular expressions?  You should consider using a proper XML parser instead which understands the intricacies of XML.

Comment: @IanRoberts you're absolutelly right, but  this is just part of the script. I'm actually using XMLReader php class to extract the content, but I need to sanitize and replace some deep level tags in order to export these tags as content inside another xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex works, but it greedily matches the start of your tag with any string representing the end of the tag. Basically, that big blue group is one big "tag" as far as regex is concerned.

Here's one way to solve this. Try [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/aO5kO1/1):

```
<w:proofErr[^>]+(?:"\/>)
```

It replaces `.*` with `[^>]*`, which tells it to match any character *except* a closing bracket.